# update dynamodb table with pandas dataframe in lambda function

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to upload 2 csv files from 2 different url's to a dynamodb table. I am using pandas to get the desired data from the url's and merge the 2 dataframes into a df3. I'm running into an issue when I use put_item to update the database. I have tried converting the pandas series into strings but that doesn't seem to work either.
Here is the lambda function:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
import numpy as np
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
import json
from decimal import Decimal

def lambda_handler(event, context): 
    
    url1 = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us.csv"
    url2 = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/time-series-19-covid-combined.csv"
    
    df1 = pd.read_csv(url1)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
    df1 = df1.drop(0)

    df2 = pd.read_csv(url2, delimiter=',')
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
    df2['Recovered'] = df2['Recovered'].fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
    df2 = df2.loc[df2['Country/Region'] == 'US', 'Recovered']
    df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
    df2.index = np.arange(1, len(df2) + 1)
    
    df3 = df1.join(df2)
    region = 'eu-west-2'
    
    try:
        dyndb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name=region)
        firstrecord = True
        for row in df1:
            if firstrecord:
                firstrecord = False
                continue
            cases = df3['cases']
            date = df3['date']
            deaths = df3['deaths']
            Recovered = df3['Recovered']
        response = dyndb.put_item(TableName='covidstatstable',
                Item={
                'cases': {'N': cases},
                'date': {'S': date},
                'deaths': {'N': deaths},
                'Recovered': {'N': Recovered},
                })

        print('Put succeeded:')
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

and here is the function logs:

```
Test Event Name
test1

Response
null

Function Logs
START RequestId: d5192687-d8ef-41dc-bd2f-efbcb1c7ff6f Version: $LATEST
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Item.cases.N, value: 1             1
2             1
3             2
4             3
5             5
...   
607    42066372
608    42274530
609    42404490
610    42551956
611    42678374
Name: cases, Length: 611, dtype: int64, type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
Invalid type for parameter Item.date.S, value: 1      2020-01-22
2      2020-01-23
3      2020-01-24
4      2020-01-25
5      2020-01-26
...    
607    2021-09-19
608    2021-09-20
609    2021-09-21
610    2021-09-22
611    2021-09-23
Name: date, Length: 611, dtype: object, type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
Invalid type for parameter Item.deaths.N, value: 1           0
2           0
3           0
4           0
5           0
...  
607    673939
608    676191
609    678556
610    681343
611    684488
Name: deaths, Length: 611, dtype: int64, type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
Invalid type for parameter Item.Recovered.N, value: 1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0
..
607    0
608    0
609    0
610    0
611    0
Name: Recovered, Length: 611, dtype: int64, type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
END RequestId: d5192687-d8ef-41dc-bd2f-efbcb1c7ff6f
REPORT RequestId: d5192687-d8ef-41dc-bd2f-efbcb1c7ff6f  Duration: 902.87 ms Billed Duration: 903 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 172 MB Init Duration: 1806.56 ms

Request ID
d5192687-d8ef-41dc-bd2f-efbcb1c7ff6f
```

Comment: you are trying to loop over rows of df1, but using the whole of df3 in each iteration. Try looping over rows of df3, and using the individual values.

Comment: `for row in df3:` and `cases = row['cases']` for all data variables.

Comment: yes I tried to iterate over df3 and the function logs display the same error. as for luks  suggestion that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: use https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/028%20-%20DynamoDB.html . can write df directly to dynamo